# Magento 2 : page speed optimization

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, performance, optimization, pagespeed

Please provide me the suggestion regarding magento 2 store speed up?
I already set the minified js and css from the admin panel.

Also find too many request in the browser, how can we reduce server request in magento 2.

Please explain how magento 2 caching work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you if want good magento pagespeed, the store must be set to production mode using following command;

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Now, for caching you can use magento's default full page cache, which does work as expected for most cases but go with third-party solutions like [Redis](https://redis.io/) or [Varnish](https://varnish-cache.org/) for more performance.

Installing and configuring these third  party caches correctly is a long process so not including it here. Redis is relatively simpler to configure.
You can follow this tutorial to install redis - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/how-to-configure-and-install-redis-on-ubuntu-linux and to configure it you can use this explanation - https://magehit.com/blog/magento-2-varnish-and-redis-configuration/

> How can we reduce server request in magento 2?

You can reduce the number of server requests drastically by bundling js files in admin or by db.

See my answer on how to it using db here - [Magento 2.2.5 : Merge and minify js and css](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240460/magento-2-2-5-merge-and-minify-js-and-css/240468#240468)

Feel free to ping me in case of any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try solutions for speed up your store below :

1. Setup store to production model

> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

2. Enable JS & CSS optimization

> Go to Stores -> “Configuration” in “Settings” Section -> “Developer” in “Advanced” Tab -> Section “JavaScript Settings” (Fields “Enable Javascript Bundling“, “Merge JavaScript Files“, “Minify JavaScript Files” change to “Yes”)
>
> Go to Stores -> “Configuration” in “Settings” Section -> “Developer” in “Advanced” Tab -> Section “CSS Settings” (Fields “Merge CSS Files“, “Minify CSS Files” change to “Yes“)

3. Content Delivery Network

> STORES ->  Configuration ->  GENERAL -> Web -> Base URLs (Secure)
> then insert your HTTPS URLs in here and bring your customers fast loading speed.

4. Have caching enabled

> Go to Stores -> “Configuration” in “Settings” Section -> “System” in “Advanced” Tab -> Section “Full Page Cache” -> Field “Caching Application” change to “Varnish Caching“, than configure it.

5. Images Optimization

> A. You image must be compressed.
> B. Product Image should use JPEG format
> C. Logo and layout should use PNG or SVG format

6. Enable Flat Categories and Products

> Go to Stores -> “Configuration” in “Settings” Section -> “Catalog” in “General” Tab -> Section “Storefront” -> Fields “Use Flat Catalog Category” and “Use Flat Catalog Product” change to “Yes”

Answer (score 0):

1. Inspect every 3rd-party extension installed
2. Choose the fastest hosting possible
3. Make sure Full Page Cache is on
4. Make sure Production Mode is on
5. Never use JS bundling
6. Enable CSS/JS minification
7. Use Built-in Cache, Skip Varnish